# Order of elements in cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can I find a natural number $n>500$ such that $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ has no element of order $6$?

Comment: What? They certainly can: The group $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_{100}$ does...

Comment: Please fix your question.

Comment: @T.Bongers maybe I'm not understanding the question I was asked, "Give an integer m greater than or equal to 500 such that Z mod m has no elements of order 6"

Comment: Hint: Lagrange's theorem is a cool theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Can you figure out when the cyclic group of order $n$ has no elements of order $k$? Consider *small* examples first.

Comment: If n is composite and k is prime? Or if n and k are relatively prime?

Comment: @Jesus, you're looking in the right direction. Try out your two conjectures on some more examples.